# Dimmer with second regular switch strange behavior

Tags: electrical, lighting, dimmer-switch

We have four can lights in the ceiling which a dimmer switch operates normally. There is a second switch across the room and it is a normal on-off type switch. If the lights are off the normal switch will turn them on normally. If the lights are on, to turn them off we must quickly switch off-on-off to make the lights go off (and they dim off, not switch off). Similarly if the lights are medium bright, a quick on-off-on at the normal switch will raise them to full brightness. This seems very odd - is something wrong or have we just never seen this before?

Related, we have another dimmer switch in the house which is mildly warm at time. When I took the cover plate off, the metal tabs (top and bottom of plastic dimmer "box") connecting to the box is quite warm, as well as the actual plastic switch box. There were no exposed wires (thinking a bare wire was touching perhaps) and everything seemed in order. I am thinking we should replace this but obviously we have not been around dimmers switches much, so confirming this is not normal.

Thanks!

Comment: What make and model is dimmer controlling the can lights? Also, how much lighting load (in watts) is on the second dimmer switch, and what's its Watt rating?

Comment: Have you ever heard of a "3-way switch"?  Can you say whether this is (or isn't) that?

Comment: The "normal" switch is a 3-way switch. I have not looked at the dimmer yet.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a bug, it's a feature (as we say in IT). It's a semi smart switch that is doing what it's supposed to.  If you toggled the dimmer switch in the same manner as the normal switch, you'd probably observe the same behavior.  I have several dimmers in my home that operate exactly as you described.

Next, dimmers can get warm to the touch, esp. if feeding several old style incandescent bulbs.  If your dimmer is compatible with LEDs, swap out the old bulbs with LEDs and the dimmer should never feel even warm again.  If not compatible, and you are running incandescent bulb, I'd strongly recommend replacing the dimmer with one that's compatible and using LED bulbs.  The energy savings are substantial.  If you live in a hot climate and use the old style bulbs, you are not only using a lot more energy to power them, but they produce a lot of heat, which your A/C will have to run longer to keep the house at set point.

Comment: Thanks! Tried to give you an up-vote, but I am too new here apparently.

Comment: Sorry, one additional question. Sometimes the dimmer's green light (on the actual switch) blinks. It goes away if we turn flip the other switch and we are not sure what makes it blink. It doesn't happen regularly.

Comment: @JScott  hmmmm. ... make and model of dimmer would help. But let's face it, dimmers are pretty inexpensive and your old one probably isn't compatible with LEDs anyway.  You'll need a 3-way dimmer to operate with the other "normal" switch.  If you go to swap it out, be SURE to take several pics of the wiring BEFORE the swap.  For some reason 3-way (2 switches controlling the same fixture) seems to flummox people around here and it's best to document everything you can carefully first.